# remote: Repository not found. Git pull shows fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/repositoryname.git/' not found when using access token

Tags: git, github

I created an access token and when I use it instead of password to pull it throws the following

```
remote: Repository not found. Git pull shows fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/repositoryname.git/' not found
```

Answer (score -3):

Actually, the permissions are not given properly for the generated token. After I've set the proper permissions, it's working fine. Go to https://github.com/settings/tokens and select your generated token then you can see the permission checkboxes. Select the appropriate permissions and update. Now your token will work properly as expected